# holding on to the previous value until a new value is fetched from the database

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I am trying to display the total number of items in a cart, which are being fetched from the database. The problem is for the slight moment that the data is being fetched, the totol number shows to be NaN. I want to know if there is a way to hold on the old value in the display until the new value is arrived.
fetching data from an async function in redux-toolkit.

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const { totalItems } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.cartState
```

I hope I am clear in stating my problem and also hope that it's not a stupid question.

Looking forward to feedback